# Angular 5 Universal: Using server.ts in Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

I used the new [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) to start a new Angular 5 project. For the new release they only give the Angular CLI version as a starter.
Everything works fine and I can run my project in production with `npm run serve:ssr`etc.

But: I have a **custom API for the node.js/express server** that acts as a wrapper for my backend.

When starting the project in development with `ng serve`or `npm run start`I have a working Angular application with automatic reload on file changes etc.
Unfortunately in development the `server.ts` file is ignored, so my API wrapper is not available.

So did anyone get the new Angular Starter Kit up and running with the `server.ts` file used in development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [Github](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/490) FriOne mentioned a better workaround using `ts-node-dev`:

```
ts-node-dev --fast --respawn server.dev.ts
```

To run this I duplicated the server.ts file to server.dev.ts only with the APIs I need to access while in dev. this way you can use `ng serve` for fast rebuilds while developing and still access your node-apis.

Answer (score 5):

As of now angular cli does not support universal to run in dev mode. You can try nodemon if watching changes is what you need:

```
nodemon --ignore dist -e ts --exec 'npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr'
```

It will restart every time you change a .ts file, but it will build the whole application again, so it is not fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you mentioned, it's not perfect. But for now it does what I need for a bit more convenience while developing!

At Github they are discussing about adding some kind of Dev-Setup for the starter, so maybe there will be some better solution in the future >> https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/490

Comment: Still nothing for hot reload using angular-universal ?